# Multiple touch in soundpool

Tags: android, button, soundpool, multi-touch

How to make multiple touch in soundpool? I have 3 button. When finger slide touch button,  like sound in piano? This my code :

```
sp = new SoundPool (5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
player1 = sp.load(this, R.raw.ndang, 1);
player2 = sp.load(this, R.raw.nding, 1);
player3 = sp.load(this, R.raw.ndung, 1);

ndang = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.ndang);
ndang.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sp.play(player1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
});

ndang = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.ndang2);
ndang.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sp.play(player1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
});

nding = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.nding);
nding.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sp.play(player2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that you want to look at is MultiTouch touch. Take a look at: http://www.passsy.de/multitouch-for-all-views/

Comment: i was combine that code with my code. But when touch the button just looping the sound, when touch slide from button 1 to button 2 just play button 1 not simultan. Do you have any sollution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a `View.OnTouchListener` or better for a piano is to create a custom view containing the whole keyboard and override `onTouchEvent`.  This will enable you to detect multiple piano key presses and key slides while minimizing code.

EDIT:

```
public class PianoView extends View {
    @Override
    onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //your code to find which key was pressed based on x,y touch
    }
}
```

or

```
public class PianoActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //your code to find which key was pressed based on x,y touch
    }
}
```

Comment: I was change with View.OnTouchListener but not respond,I  still confused use onTouchEvent, Do you can implement that metode in my code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am really a beginner for that.. But i will keep trying..

Answer (score 2):

May this help you :  http://www.martinhoeller.net/2012/01/13/developing-a-musical-instrument-app-for-android/

Comment: I was download that, but different, because that use AudioTrack while i use the SoundPool. Thanks for your answer...